# Jenkins MSbuild multiple files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to use Jenkins's MSbuild to build multiple project. Is it possible? 
Maybe use semicolons to separate projects, like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work that way. But you could add another MSBuild-Step for each project.

If you don't want to repeat the *'Command Line Arguments'* every time one solution could be to check the 'Pass build variables as properties' . Then in *'Buildenvironment'* you choose *'Inject environment variables to the build process'* and add something like `BUILD_ARGS="/t:rebuild ..."` to *'Properties Content'* and add `${BUILD_ARGS}` (or `%BUILD_ARGS%`) to *'Command Line Arguments'*

If you want to manage only one job with one build step, you can do this by using a *Windows batch-file* build-step. For example:

```
set BUILD_ARGS="/t:rebuild /p:VisualStudioVersion=11"

msbuild projectA.sln %BUILD_ARGS%
msbuild projectB.sln %BUILD_ARGS%
```

In this case, you usually have to call something like `call "C:\<path-to-your-visual-studio-ins>\VC\vcvars.bat"` initially, depending on your required build environment.
Also, you may want to handle errors. Therefore you could add for example `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO :eof` after each `msbuild` line.

Comment: I don't want to create many **Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild** sections. I want build many projects in one section. I see something like create a MSBuild xml for **MSBuild Build File**.

Comment: Your suggestion is good, actually I use that way at beginning. Now I create multiple sections to solve the problem and I find this solution https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd576348.aspx

Comment: I tried using a Windows batch-file build-step, but it can't find `msbuild` when I do that, even when I've previously ran an MSBuild step earlier in the pipeline. How can I add msbuild to the path so that jenkins can find it when executing the Windows Batch-file step?