# Why MSbuild does not build multiple projects in single action using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

To build .NET projects, am using "Build a Visual Studio project or Solution using MSBuild" plugin under Build section in Jenkins job.

By using this, i can run only one project file alone by specifying the below details.

```
MSBuild Version: msbuild(set through environment variables)
MSBuild Build File: ProjectA.sln 
Command Line Arguments:  /p:Configuration=Release
```

I have tried by giving another project file by giving space and comma next to the first project. Jenkins job build ends in failure. I could not build more than one project using this plugin in my jenkins job.

Normally we can do this using iteration(getting all the solution files in a particular directory and build it).

But in jenkins, is this possible by looping the "Build a Visual Studio project or Solution using MSBuild" or any other option available(plugin) to achieve this like pass multiple projects to **MSBuild Build File:** and build in single step(instead of again and again using "Build a Visual Studio project or Solution using MSBuild" to build the remaining projects?

Comment: Similar query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309260/jenkins-msbuild-multiple-files

Comment: @ MichaelMao, We are searching a lot but didnt get any relavant information. If you have solution for this, please help us.

Comment: Why is the linked question not relevant? As far as I can see it provides a solution to the exact same problem you're having? (though instead of a batch files, you could use a powershell script, or use an msbuild file which in turn builds all solutions you need, or..., but the principle remains the same: add an 'intermediate' way to build multiple solutions ad have jenkins invoke that)

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a single .sln file - you can control which projects are being built for a specific configuration (in your case it's Release). Just include necessary projects for build in Configuration manager in Visual Studio.

As an alternative way- you can create very simple msbuild script which will contain all your projects\solutions you want to build and use that aggregated build script in your Jenkins task.

NB: to be a bit pedantic - solution files are not msbuild files, but `.*proj` usually are. Normally you'd have a single solution file where all your projects are included. When msbuild.exe called to build solution file - it autogenerates custom build script based on all settings in your .sln file and then builds that auto-generated script...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to build multiple solutions using the msbuild plugin.

The plugin expects one solution and configuration.

You could use one of the script plugins to perform the iteration over the workspace directory and execute the msbuild for each solution, **or** as mentioned above you could role your own msbuild file.

However this does not allow you to use Jenkins as it was really intended to be used.

The idea is to basically build as much in parallel as possible. You have to setup the dependencies though as you are the one that knows what solution/project is dependent upon another solution/project.

I have about ~200 Visual Studio solution configurations building under Jenkins using this approach (works out at just over 500 projects). It's not quick to setup but has now been stable for about 4 years now.

**Note:**
The downside with Visual Studio is that the pdbserver can end up being killed by Jenkins. It looks like the latest msbuild plugin deals with this issue.

There are a number of ways around this, that are documented on the Jenkins website. I've gone a little bit further and I stop and restart the pdbserver every 10 to 15 jobs as I have found it to not be particularly stable.